# Using content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded to upload file in JAVA

Tags: java, http, post, file-upload

I want to upload a file using java client to server where content type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded .

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)  has nice explanation on how to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded but I coudn't find a way to upload file using this .

Are there any hints to do this? (Don't suggest to use multipart/form-data)

Comment: Percentile-encoded upload? Really? Why not put the entire entire file in the HTTP body, and set the content type to mime of the file? If server expects urlencoded data: 1) Its plain stupid. 2) upload file size can probably increase to around 3 times.

Comment: I have to submit data of a form using java. where there are multiple elements to be submitted to server. one of them is a File (File size is not a problem here for me)

Comment: Use multipart form data in that case. I don't understand why you wouldn't want a standard approach. URLEncoding file data is bad, very bad.